# Include one Dafny file in another

Tags: dafny

I want to reuse the same Dafny code in several programs. Is it possible to include one Dafny file in another? The manual does not describe any way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in December 2013 support for an "include" statement was [added to Dafny](https://dafny.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/c9fe93d11e86#file_diff_Test/dafny0/Include.dfy), the syntax is:

```
include "Includee.dfy"
```